# mod_wsgi: Multiple instances of the same app, with different configurations

Tags: mod-wsgi

I want to host multiple instances of an application with different configurations. I have it currently set up like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /foo /path/to/app.wsgi
<Location /foo>
    SetEnv CONFIG foo.conf
</Location>

WSGIScriptAlias /bar /path/to/app.wsgi
<Location /bar>
    SetEnv CONFIG bar.conf
</Location>
```

app.wsgi then looks like this:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    if not config.is_loaded:
        config.load(environ.get("CONFIG"))
    [...]
```

This seems to work, but I wonder if it is correct - ie will requests for `/foo` *always* arrive at an instance of the app that loaded `foo.conf`?

Also, is there a better way to set this up? (Note: I need this to run on Windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figured it out through RTFM :-)

The default `WSGIApplicationGroup %{RESOURCE}` should apply, with `%{RESOURCE}` being distinct for the `/foo` and `/bar` aliases.

Since each application group is executed in it's own sub-interpreter, there should in fact always be distinct instances of the application for the two locations.